# HTML5 input download (client only) seems to be limited by size

Tags: javascript, html, download

I want to download a file (client only) which contains a stringified JSON object. For months everything went well until I needed to stringify a big json object.

The text file is always created but the JSON object is simply cut off(if I change the json object it is cut off in different places).

I checked and the whole JSON object is correctly stringified and put into the href attribute but it is not totally present in the downloaded text file.

```
const file = document.createElement('a');
            file.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + JSON.stringify(jsonObj));
            file.setAttribute('id', 'tcDownload');
            file.setAttribute('download', fileName);
            file.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(file);

            file.click();
            document.body.removeChild(file);
```

So I am wondering if where is some sort of size restriction while using client based downloading.

Works fine now thank you:  epascarello

SOLUTION:

```
const str = JSON.stringify(tc);
var blob = new Blob(str.split(''), {type: 'text/plain'});
const file = document.createElement('a');
file.download = 'myFile.txt';
file.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

document.body.appendChild(file);
file.click();
```

Comment: Probably better off with using a blob since data urls are limited https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL